# Sliding window of count distinct users for 12 months

Tags: sql, count, window, amazon-athena, sliding-window

I have a fairly basic dataset, where I have a table containing a timestamp of every time a user interacts with an app. An active user is classified as someone who has in the previous 12 months interacted with the app at least once.

I need to produce a table, which tells me day by day (going back n days) how many "active" users there were in the prior 12 month period. I need to run the query in Amazon Athena

A possible complexity is the fact that one user could interact with the app every day. I was wondering what the best window function could be to capture this.

The data is in the format;

```
A   Opened App  10/04/2020
A   Opened App  10/02/2020
A   Opened App  05/01/2020
B   Opened App  12/03/2020
B   Opened App  02/01/2019
B   Opened App  20/07/2018
C   Opened App  19/04/2019
```

I need a resulting table of

```
20/04/2020  2 (A and B)
19/04/2020  2 (A and B)
18/04/2020  3 (all three)
... 
04/01/2020  1 (Only C)
...
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `count(distinct)` with a `range` window function:

```
select distinct date,
       count(distinct user) over (order by date range between interval '1 year' preceding and current row) as num_active_users
from t;
```

Not all databases support this syntax.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know what the syntax could be for Athena? I am currently trying;


select distinct date(timestamp),
       count(distinct id) over (order by date(timestamp) range between interval '1' year
                                   preceding and current row) as num_active_users
from table;



getting an error 

Window frame start value type must be INTEGER or BIGINT(actual interval year to month)

Comment: @Steve . . . I don't have direct access to Athena and find it very hard to figure out what the right syntax is, because it seems to use an older version of Presto.  Do you know where there is good documentation specifically about Athena?

Comment: Here's the SQL Reference for Amazon Athena: [SQL Reference for Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ddl-sql-reference.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein . . . And this is where the functions reference:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions-operators-reference-section.html.  Presto is now far beyond that version.